# How to run tests in a ROS package?

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a ROS package, containing some nodes/scripts/messages etc, all laid out using the [recommended folder structure.](http://www.artificialhumancompanions.com/structure-python-based-ros-package/) I'm not trying to execute some tests using the standard `catkin_make run_tests` and I'm getting the error:

```
The specified base path "my_ros_package" contains a package but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it's saying I need to create a ROS workspace...just to run tests? This seems a little strange to me. I've written a ton of unittests for Python packages, mostly using the Tox tool, and this handles creating a virtualenv, installing all your dependencies, and then running your tests, all from your Python package. I've never had to create a second Python package just to run my first package's tests.

If you've created a ROS project in a git repo, how are you supposed to test it? Create another git repo containing a "test" ROS workspace...which then clones your first repo? That seems redundant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284878/how-to-run-tests-in-a-ros-package?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure you’re not in “src” directory. You should be in your “~/catkin_ws” directory and then run this command in terminal:
catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [smartbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/32951/smartbot/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-03-10**:
Yes, I know. Why would I pollute my catkin_ws directory by running unittests in it?

**Comment by [smartbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/32951/smartbot/) on 2018-03-11**:
I don't understand what do you mean by polluting your workspace directory. Anyways, my answer was depending on the error you getting as you have an issue with workspace structure.

**Comment by [smartbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/32951/smartbot/) on 2018-03-11**:
Reference: https://answers.ros.org/question/221538/the-specified-base-path-homeruicatkin_ws-contains-a-package-but-catkin_make-must-be-invoked-in-the-root-of-workspace-how-can-i-fix-it/